# Programmatically add wifi networks on Android

Tags: wi-fi, adb

I have a list of about 100 WiFi SSIDs and passwords that I've extracted from my old phone and I want to add them to the new phone that runs Android 10 and I couldn't find any useful information on the net as everything seems outdated and not working.

A bit about my phone: it's a OnePlus 7 with OxygenOS 10.0.1, rooted with TWRP and Magisk. The wifi networks come from an old OnePlus One with Cyanogenmod wich is *not* rooted. I obtained the passwords following https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/86zkzf/restoring_wifi_passwords_from_old_device/

The closest thing I've found is this: https://github.com/steinwurf/adb-join-wifi but it works only one network at the time and it doesn't work very well, often passwords aren't added and I have problem escaping the SSID and passwords.

I've also tried to look for `wpa_supplicant.conf` but apparently it's not used anymore, instead I've found a file called `WifiConfigStore.xml` but I'm not sure if it can be edited manually or it needs a program, I tried to use `wpa_cli` but I get an error at startup, I looked for apps but nothing like I need.

I believe the way to go is through `WifiConfigStore.xml` but its format looks non trivial so that I'm not confident to update it manually plus there's the change it's managed by a service and any change I make will be erased.

How can I add programmatically my networks? Is there an adb command, a file I could edit on the phone or an app that can help me with this?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes it is rooted. I've updated the post

Comment: Do you access to the old phone?

Comment: Yes but the old phone is not rooted. I discovered the wifi passwords following https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/86zkzf/restoring_wifi_passwords_from_old_device/

Comment: Your best chance is to copy WifiConfigStore.xml from old phone to new phone.

Comment: Have you tried Google's backup service, which can migrate such data like WiFi SSIDs and network credentials?

Comment: No, I havent tried Google backup for wifi. Can Android 6 do it? (Meanwhile I'm searching myself...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also had the same problem with losing all WiFi networks when upgrading LineageOS, so I've written a tool which will convert your old `wpa_supplicant.conf` to new `WifiConfigStore.xml` (and I'm not using Google accounts or other "upload all my stuff to some cloud" privacy nightmares)

You can find it here: https://github.com/mnalis/android-wifi-upgrade

Even with just SSID/passwords list and without original `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, file format for `WifiConfigStore.xml` is not really complex (it is just very verbose). With minimal programming you can use template in my code used for filling it to replace `$SSID` and other variables in order to generate it from your list).

Note that it will require root (or recovery rom with full adb or filemanager access) on your new android device in order to actually upload newly created `WifiConfigStore.xml` to the phone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't want to spend the time myself to learn that format :D